# Converting Fully connected layers into Convolutional layers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I've read another post made about converting FC layers into convolutional layers in this post:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263349/how-to-convert-fully-connected-layer-into-convolutional-layer ,
but i don't understand how you get the 4096x1x1 in the last calculations. I know that after going trough the convolution layers and the pooling that we end up with a layer of 7x7x512

I got this from this github post: https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convert

> Conversely, any FC layer can be converted to a CONV layer. For example, an FC layer with K=4096 that is looking at some input volume of size 7×7×512 can be equivalently expressed as a CONV layer with F=7,P=0,S=1,K=4096. In other words, we are setting the filter size to be exactly the size of the input volume, and hence the output will simply be 1×1×4096 since only a single depth column “fits” across the input volume, giving identical result as the initial FC layer.

It's the math i don't completely understand. In the other post, the author wrote

> In this example, as far as I understood, the converted CONV layer should have the shape (7,7,512), meaning (width, height, feature dimension). And we have 4096 filters. And the output of each filter's spatial size can be calculated as (7-7+0)/1 + 1 = 1. Therefore we have a 1x1x4096 vector as output.

But where do you get the other 7 from? do you calculate the convolutional layer with itself? and that's how you end up with 1x1x4096?

Consider I have a CNN that consists of Input(234×234)-Conv(7,32,1)-Pool(2,2)-Conv(7,32,1)-Pool(2,2)Conv(7,32,1)-Pool(2,2)-FC(1024)-FC(1024)-FC(1000). And zero-padding is not used.
Running this through and calculating conv layers and pooling should leave us at 24x24x32 at last pooling if i'm not wrong. Stride is 1 for the conv layers.

1. 234x234x1 > conv7x7x32 > (234-7)/1+1 = 228
2. 228x228x32 > pool2x2 > (228 - 2 )/2 + 1 = 114
3. 114x114x32 > conv7x7x32 > (114 - 7 ) / 1 + 1 = 108
4. 108x108x32 > pool2x2 > (108-2)/2 + 1 = 54
5. 54x54x32 > conv7x7x32 > (54-7)/1 + 1 = 48
6. 48x48x32 > pool2x2 > (48-2)/2 + 1 = 24
7. 24x24x32
8. (24-24)/1 + 1 = 1 > 1024x1x1, 1024x1x1, 1000x1x1

Is this the right way to convert the FC layers into convolutional layers?

Comment: I feel like you answered your own question already. Basically, yes, your example computation is correct.

Comment: @xdurch0 Really? It feels like it's too easy to convert it then. Like the calculations beforehand is not needed. So every fully connected layer just becomes a 1x1x(number of layers) when converted to convolutional layers? What is then the use of the calculations and pooling beforehand?

Comment: Well not quite, the first "fully-connected" layer needs to cover the remaining image. E.g. the 7x7x layer in the example you quoted. In your case, it would need to be a 24x24x(number_of_units) filter size layer. *After* that, all remaining layers are 1x1x(number_of_units). So you do need to make the calculation to find out what the feature map size after the last "real" convolution is.

Comment: Ah, i think i understand. So in my case, the first FC layer will become 24x1024x1 (filter size, number of units, stride). Since it will then only take 1 go to go through the layer. And the next ones will be 1x1024x1, and 1x1000x1 in convolutional layers